How to incorporate a lucky draw into screenmanager in Kivy (eg. pressing a button and one of the randomly selected 6 windows will show up)
So I am working on a project with some of my friends, and we are trying to incorporate the element of lucky drawing to open different windows with ScreenManager on Kivy, but I am struggling to find a way to apply it to the code.
I thought of using the random module also, but I don't know where to start. And using the random functions inside the """ """ part also won't work, so I am out of ideas.
I'm still really new to Kivy, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not looking for just a big piece of code that I can just copy and paste into Visual Studio, but rather some ideas and methods of how I can use to incorporate it so I can actually learn what is going on.
This is what I am trying to achieve:

There are one page with a button, when pressed, it will choose one out of 5 other different windows and open it.

This is the code that I am currently working on:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import random

scene_manager = """

ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    Scene1:
    Scene2:
    Scene3:
    Scene4:
    Scene5:
    
<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menuscreen'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Click to draw'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        on_press: root.manager.current = ??? idk
        
<Scene1>:
    name: 'scene1'
    MDLabel:
        text: "This is the first path"
        halign: "center"

<Scene2>:
    name: 'scene2'
    MDLabel:
        text: "This is the second path"
        halign: "center"
    
<Scene3>:
    name: 'scene3'
    MDLabel:
        text: "This is the third path"
        halign: "center"

<Scene4>:
    name: 'scene4'
    MDLabel:
        text: "This is the fourth path"
        halign: "center"

<Scene5>:
    name: 'scene5'
    MDLabel:
        text: "This is the fifth path"
        halign: "center"

        
"""


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Scene1(Screen):
    pass

class Scene2(Screen):
    pass

class Scene3(Screen):
    pass

class Scene4(Screen):
    pass

class Scene5(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menuscreen'))
sm.add_widget(Scene1(name='scene1'))
sm.add_widget(Scene2(name='scene2'))
sm.add_widget(Scene3(name='scene3'))
sm.add_widget(Scene4(name='scene4'))
sm.add_widget(Scene5(name='scene5'))


class Test(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(scene_manager)
        return screen


Test().run()


Instead of trying to do it all in kv, why not just call a method in either the App or in MenuScreen that chooses a random number and selects that number Screen from ScreenManager.screens.

Hello, maybe you could try writing a button handling event. Then use random.choice() in the event handler to randomly select the screen to toggle. Is this the desired effect possible?

@Jeanneli hello, thank you for the suggestion. But unfortunately I tried the same thing before by writing the following in the scene_manager:
on_press: root.manager.current = random.choice('scene1', 'scene2', 'scene3', 'scene 4', scene5)
Sadly it just gives me an error when I click on the button:  NameError: name 'random' is not defined. Did you forget to import 'random'? I guess it just dosen't recognize anything when inside kv.

@JohnAnderson Thank you for your help but how do I refer the screens in the method written in 'App'? Because what I write outside of kv dosen't seem to affect thats inside the file, sorry if this sounds confusing but I don't know how to phrase it.

sorry, then if you use the Clock object of kivy to schedule the event. Create different methods to control the start and stop then switch_to to the screen. Will this have the desired effect?

The message is telling you what the problem is. You need to import random in the kv file. See the documentation.

You can define a method in, for example, the App:
class Test(MDApp):

    def do_random_screen(self):
        screen = random.choice(self.root.screens)
        # make sure the new screen is not the current screen
        while screen == self.root.current_screen:
            screen = random.choice(self.root.screens)
        self.root.current = screen.name

Then use that method in your kv:
<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menuscreen'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Click to draw'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        # on_press: root.manager.current = ??? idk
        on_press: app.do_random_screen()


I realized that I've completely ignored self.root.screens, Ishould really dig into the documentation more, thank you for pointing it out. I understand how to create similar functions now and can contiune with the project, thanks a lot for your help! :)
